# How to prove that a topological space is connected iff it has exactly two clopen subsets?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

The question is in the title, I'll rephrase it slightly here.

I am wondering how to prove that a topological space $X$ is connected if and only if it has exactly two clopen (closed and open) subsets.

Apart from writing down the definitions of connected, open and closed I really have no idea how to prove this. Any suggestions?

Comment: If a topological space can be written as the disjoint union of two open components, what can be said about the complements of those components?

Comment: What if your space $X$ is the empty space? It only has one clopen subset: itself.

Comment: @kahen: Many texts specify that a topological space is a non-empty set equipped with a topology.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$(\Leftarrow)$: Considering the contrapositive... Let $X$ be a disconnected topological space. That is to say, there exist non-empty open subsets $U$, $V \subset X$ such that $U \cap V = \emptyset $ and $U \cup V=X$. Here $U$ and $V$ are clopen subsets of $X$ since $U^c=V$ and $V^c=U$.

$(\Rightarrow)$: Suppose now that $X$ is connected. Then there exist two clopen subsets of $X$, namely $\emptyset$ and $X$ itself. Here, recall that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are clopen by definition.

Comment: thanks! But I guess the argument for the $\Rightarrow$ isn't entirely complete, because we also have to consider the possiblity that there are more than or less than 2 clopen subsets of $X$, shouldn't we?

Comment: @Max: So long as $X$ is non-empty, there cannot be fewer than $2$ clopen subsets of $X$. $X$ and $\emptyset$ are necessarily clopen, regardless of the topology on $X$. A set is clopen if and only if its complement is clopen, so if there *were* any other clopen sets, then $X$ would have a separation, impossible since $X$ is connected.

Comment: Metin: For $(\Leftarrow)$, you need to specify that $U,V$ are non-empty.

Comment: Sure, forgot to mention. Thanks...

Comment: Sir as $X=U\cup V$ and $U\cap V$ is empty. Hence $U\subset V^{c}$ and $V\subset U^{c}$. How $U=V^{c}$ ?

Answer (score 7):

Always there are at least two clopen subsets, namely $\emptyset,X$. If there is another one, let's say $U$, then $U\neq\emptyset$ and $U\neq X$.
 Consider the subsets $U$ and $U^c$ to show that $X$ is disconnected.

Answer (score 4):

We would like to prove that $X$ is connected iff the only sets in $X$ that are clopen are $\varnothing$ and $X$.

$\Rightarrow$: (by contrapositive). Assume that there is a clopen subset $A$ of $X$ such that $A\neq \varnothing$ and $A\neq X$. Then the pair $(A, A^c)$ forms a separation of $X$. Thus, $X$ is not connected.

$\Leftarrow$: (by contrapositive). Suppose $X$ is not connected. Then there exist two nonempty disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$ such that $X=A\cup B$. This implies that $A$ and $B$ are complement to each other. Thus, $A=B^c$. Hence, $A$ is closed. Therefore, $A$ is a clopen subset of $X$ satisfying $A\neq \varnothing$ and $A\neq X$.

Comment: Sir, How that implise $A$ and $B$ are complement of each other.

Comment: Sir as $X=A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ is empty. Hence $A\subset B^{c}$ and $B\subset A^{c}$. How $A=B^{c}$ ?

Comment: @ Akash Patalwanshi Since $A\cap B=\varnothing$, $A\subset B^c$. Since $X=A\cup B$ then taking complement to both sides and using De Morgans Law, we get $A^c\cap B^c=\varnothing$. This implies that $B^c\subset A$. Equality follows.